# gem5: Support for multicore for X86 O3 CPU Full System with classical memory

Tags: x86, multicore, gem5

I am running into trouble running full system simulation with 2 X86 O3 cores and classical memory system where the system seems to get stuck during script execution. I read in other (relatively) old posts that multicore might not be supported for this configuration (X86-O3-classical memory).

I was just wondering if this is still the case or if I should investigate more to see if I am doing something wrong.

The same configuration works for 1 X86 O3 core as well as for multicore AtomicSimple cores.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the answer, also ping mailing list.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your reply, Ciro

Comment: Were you able to get it to work? Have you tried with the Ruby model instead of the classical model? Have you tried in SE mode instead of FS mode?

Comment: Did it work for you? I was trying to use 2 X86 O3 in SE mode with ruby memory, but the simulation does not stop . can anyone please help, I used  
""build/X86_MESI_Three_Level/gem5.opt configs/example/se.py -n 2 --ruby --cpu-type=DerivO3CPU -c 'tests/test-progs/hello/bin/x86/linux/hello;tests/test-progs/hello/bin/x86/linux/hello' """

Comment: I have been using Ruby lately instead of classical memory system, I was also running full system simulations. I am not sure if this makes any difference